# I want to fetch loginID and password from below code

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, automation, fs

```
const fs = require('fs');
// var fileRefer=new Array();
 var fileRefer = fs.readFileSync('D:\\NgageAuto\\LoginID\\Creds.txt').toString().split("\n");
    for(i in fileRefer) {
      console.log(fileRefer[i]);
        }
```

Ouput:- Date: 2021-11-08 16:56:42      LoginID: pvgA1245  Password: Root@123
it's one of the example which is in file i want LoginID value i.e "pvgA1245 and password value i.e Root@123

Please , help me how can i make it!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: by taking it in 2 dimensional but it's not good approach , like every thing will behave like an element

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are hundreds of solutions to this problem, some having advantages in different scenarios then others.

Here are some for using `split()` or using a regex match. Each either using destructuring or just "normally assign" the variables. Regex has the advantage, that it can be used more flexible for example if sometimes the line schema is different and Password is missing. But if you can be sure that the schema is always the same or just wanna skip lines that don't have all values, `split()` is totally fine.

You would just add the relevant code snippet inside your `for` loop

```js
let i = "Date: 2021-11-08 16:56:42 LoginID: pvgA1245 Password: Root@123";

// split and destructure
const [ , , , , id, ,pw,] = i.split(" ");
console.log(id, pw);


// split and normally assign
const a = i.split(" ");
const id2 = a[4];
const pw2 = a[6];
console.log(id2, pw2);

// regex and destructure
const [, id3, pw3] = i.match(/(?:LoginID: ([^\s]*)) ?(?:Password: ([^\s]*))/);
console.log(id3, pw3);

// regex and normally assign
const m = i.match(/(?:LoginID: ([^\s]*)) ?(?:Password: ([^\s]*))/);
const id4 = m[1];
const pw4 = m[2];
console.log(id4, pw4);
```

Comment: ya its fine but when i am giving code inside for loop it's giving me undefined undefined only.
Date: 2021-11-08 12:22:46      LoginID: ac1175  Password: undefined
Date: 2021-11-08 12:28:18      LoginID: acb1176  Password: undefined
Date: 2021-11-08 12:47:38      LoginID: nab1177  Password: undefined
Date: 2021-11-08 12:58:44      LoginID: fab1178  Password: undefined
you also try with this and tell please

Comment: I'm not sure what your are trying to say. So if you paste e.g. the two lines below `// split and destructure` from my code example into your `for` loop, what is logged to console? please also try to use some formatting for your output examples to make them easier to read e.g. by wrapping each output line in backticks

Comment: for (i in fileRefer) {
  let s = fileRefer[i];
  const [, , , , id, ,pw,] = s.split(" ");
  console.log(id, pw);
}
Output:-C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\test.js
58

undefined undefined

Comment: R u able to detect what's the problem?

Comment: try this: `for (const s of fileRefer){console.log(s); const array = s.split(" "); console.log(array); const [, , , , id, ,pw,] = array; console.log(id, pw);}` if it does not work please provide the output of the log statements.

Comment: Same giving "undefined undefined" only

Comment: "if it does not work please provide the output of the log statements"... there are 3 log statements in the snippet i gave you last. I cannot help you if you don't provide me with sufficient information, since i cannot see what is happening on your screen. You could also provide a version of the creds.txt (a few entries 3-5 would be enough and change passwords and ids if they are confidential) So i would be able to test on my own machine.

Comment: here are some entries for creds.txt
Date: 2021-11-08 16:00:58      LoginID: pvgA1203 Password: undefined
Date: 2021-11-08 16:03:13      LoginID: pvgA1204 Password: Root@123
Date: 2021-11-08 16:04:32      LoginID: pvgA1205 Password: Root@123
Date: 2021-11-08 16:05:12      LoginID: pvgA1206 Password: Root@123
Date: 2021-11-08 16:07:42      LoginID: pvgA1207 Password: Root@123
Date: 2021-11-08 16:08:29      LoginID: pvgA1208 Password: Root@123
Date: 2021-11-08 16:09:20      LoginID: pvgA1209 Password: Root@123

Please , test and let me know

Comment: it got worked :)
Thank you , space issue was there only.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. It would be nice to know what you did to achieve this. Also if my answer was basically correct, it would be nice if you could accept it :)

Comment: Ya buddy it was correct only , Tysm :)